# Rewrite rule working for 1-4 parameters but not for 1 parameter

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the below RewriteRule which I am using on my site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /code.php?name=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /code.php?name=$1&state=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /code.php?name=$1&state=$2&district=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /code.php?name=$1&state=$2&district=$3&city=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /code.php?name=$1&state=$2&district=$3&city=$4&branch=$5 [L]
```

All last 4 rules are working fine, but the first rule is throwing 500 errors whenever accessed. I was experimenting with this for an hour. Ended up with a solution which is little weird. I edited the first rule:

```
 RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /code.php?name=$1 [L]
```

It's working when I add a forward slash after the query parameter, but throws a 404 error when there's no forward slash.

Any help would be great! Cheers.

Comment: 500 errors or error 500? Please add a sample URI that generates the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `+` quantifier instead of `*` and reverse order of your rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /code.php?name=$1&state=$2&district=$3&city=$4&branch=$5 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /code.php?name=$1&state=$2&district=$3&city=$4 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /code.php?name=$1&state=$2&district=$3 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /code.php?name=$1&state=$2 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /code.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Dayum! Same error. Removing ? Of the last rule of your answer makes it work, but with a forward slash and if the forward slash is not present its throwing 404 error. :(

Comment: Which URL is giving you 500 error and which one is giving 404?

Comment: It works when I edit the last rule of your answer, i.e. to 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /code.php?name=$1 [L,QSA]
Where this is no question mark before $. But I have to add a forward slash at the end of URL else without it, error 404 is generated.

Comment: Here is the sample URL which generates the error: [Bankcodes.co](http://www.bankcodes.co/HDFC%20Bank/). Try removing the forward slash, which is at the end of the URL.

Comment: Great! It worked now. Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it. :). If you could, Please tell me what was the problem because of error 404 was generated.

Cheers!

Comment: It was giving 500 error because this regex `^([^/]+)/?$` was matching `/HDFCBank` and then target URI `/code.php` as well causing it to loop infinitely. With slash added in the end of course 500 was solved since  `/code.php` didn't match `^([^/]+)/$`. However it won't match `/HDFCBank` and generate 404. Now with first rule it avoids all the below rules for an existing file and directory and stops infinite looping.